# Where is the application registration authentication key?

Tags: azure

In the help at  [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/key-vault/key-vault-get-started)
under the section [Register an application with Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/key-vault/key-vault-get-started#register) 
it is mentioned

"Applications that use a key vault must authenticate by using a token from Azure Active Directory. To do this, the owner of the application must first register the application in their Azure Active Directory. At the end of registration, the application owner gets the following values:

1) An Application ID

2) An authentication key (also known as the shared secret).

The application must present both these values to Azure Active Directory, to get a token."

I have just created an application registration and I can see an Application ID  but where do I find the authentication key?

The steps do show how to add a key manually, is that what is meant, I have to add a key and then I will have one?

The instructions say

"9. On the Settings blade click on keys

10.Type in a description in the Key description box and select a duration, and then click SAVE. The page refreshes and now shows a key value.

11. You will use the Application ID and the Key information in the next step to set permissions on your vault."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a Key within the Application Settings. Check [Get application ID and authentication key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#get-application-id-and-authentication-key) for further information:

[image]

Comment: Given I can choose the name, what makes this key an authentication key?

Comment: The name is only for you to see for what you have generate the key. If you press save, Azure will generate the authentication key and you have to copy it - you can only see it once.

Comment: What makes it an "authentication key" ? If I add lots of keys can I use any of them for authenticating?

Comment: Yes. You are greating a Service Principal which has a client id (appid) and a client secret (key) to authenticate. Similar is a User Principal which has a Username and Password.

Comment: I am still confused, I asked a related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50983345/how-do-i-use-an-application-id-and-one-of-its-keys-to-authenticate